# What is the Regex in sketch engine's concordance for space inside CQL

Tags: regex, whitespace, cql, corpus, sketching

I'm having troubles with a query in my corpus. What I need to find are all the instances where there is a dot that is neither preceded nor followed by a space, so for example `a.a b.b c.c`. I've found the Regex for space in this page https://www.sketchengine.eu/guide/regular-expressions/#toggle-id-2 which should be `[[:space:]]` for every whitespace character (space, new line, tab, carriage return).

My thought was I would built a CQL inside concordance that would search for not space (with the !), a dot and again not a space like this:

```
[lemma!="[[:space:]]"] [lemma="\."] [lemma!="[[:space:]]"]
```

but it is not working. I've tried to search for the regular expression alone `[[:space:]]` but it does not work either. I've also tried it with the `\s`:

```
[lemma="[\s]"] [lemma="\."] [lemma="[\s]"] and [lemma="\s"] [lemma="\."] [lemma="\s"]
```

and the  "less-than sign"/s"greater-than sign""less-than sign"s"greater-than sign" which I know it only marks the end and start of a new paragraph, but would still be a start

```
[lemma="</s><s>"] [lemma="\."] [lemma="</s><s>"]
```

But still to no avail.

I've tried to solve the problem in another way, by saying that the dot must be preceded and followed by a letter (I don't need numbers or symbols anyway) with this research:

```
[lemma="[[:alpha:]]*"] [lemma="\."] [lemma="[[:alpha:]]*"]
```

But it is not finding me all the results.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong in my Regex/CQL?

Comment: It is written where you referenced to: "*Since CQL criteria are set for individual tokens separately, the use of a space is generally a mistake and will not produce the required result.*"

Comment: yes, but I don't want to put a space into my CQL, I did not write spaces inside the CQL. I just want to find spaces inside of my corpus

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[lemma=".*(^|\S)\.($|\S).*"]
```

`\S` means any non-whitespace character. So this matches `.` preceded by either the beginning of the string or a non-space, and followed by either the end of the string or a non-space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not working. The concordance tool is still finding all the results as if I was doing a character search of the full stop (.)

Comment: Can you give an example of something it's matching that it shouldn't?

Comment: Sure. Here are some examples that I've directly copied from my results:
- possono sfuggire attraverso il liquido stesso . " Vabbè, anche se lo sapesse
- ad es . violenza sessuale
- capitolo F. Specificità delle persone trans*
As you can see, there is still a space after and / or before the full stop. There are also still all the examples like this one
- dare il mio consenso a questi esami . </s> <s> 
with the paragraph ending